# colored table with some bold colored lines

Tags: tables, color, bold

How can I have a table with the following specifications:

1. The top and bottom lines are bold and all other horizontal and vertical lines are normal.
2. The whole table lines (including top and bottom lines) are in red color.
3. The whole table have a yellow background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possibility using the [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabu}{| l | l | l |}
\taburowcolors1{yellow!90!black..yellow!90!black} 
\taburulecolor{red}
\tabucline[1pt]- 
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
\tabucline- 
column1b & column2b & column3b \\
\tabucline- 
column1c & column2c & column3c \\
\tabucline- 
column1d & column2d & column3d \\
\tabucline[1pt]- 
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a personal suggestion, vertical rules are not necessary and your table will look better without them.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\arrayrulecolor{red}
\def\widehline{%
\noalign{\global\dimen1 \arrayrulewidth
\global\arrayrulewidth8\arrayrulewidth}%
\hline
\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\dimen1 }}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{yellow}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\widehline
1&2\\
\hline
aa&bb\\
aaa&bbb\\
\hline
3&4\\
\widehline
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly `\fboxsep=0pt`?

Comment: @egreg, possibly, or possibly the OP likes having a border with the yellow being bigger than the table. As @egreg hints if you want the yellow background tight to the table, locally set `\fboxsep` to zero.

Comment: How can I have vertically centered cells?

Comment: Well that is a completely different question. Perhaps `m` column type from the `array` package.

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[rules/color=red,hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \arraycolor{yellow}
\Body
\Hline[tikz={red, very thick}]
  un     & deux     & trois  & quatre \\
  cinq   & six      & sept   & huit \\
  neuf   & dix      & onze   & douze \\
  treize & quatorze & quinze & seize \\
\Hline[tikz={red, very thick}]
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Simple in the best solution! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Well, in this simple case `tabularray` can compete in code efficiency with `NiceTabular` :-)

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{cells ={c, yellow!30},
             hlines={red}, hline{1,5}={1pt},
             vlines={red},
             }
% body
  un     & deux     & trois  & quatre \\
  cinq   & six      & sept   & huit \\
  neuf   & dix      & onze   & douze \\
  treize & quatorze & quinze & seize \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

after one compilation the result is almost the same:

[image]

**Edit:**
With version 2021M (2021-08-01) the table preaqble can be simplified to:

```
\begin{tblr}{cells ={c, yellow!30},
             hlines={red}, hline{1,Z}={1pt}, % <--- observe Z, it indicate the last line in table
             vlines={red},
             }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in Adobe Reader, at some levels of zoom, some vertical rules disappear.

Comment: @F.Pantigny, this may be a case, so as I stated in my comment below your answer, `NiceTabular` is the best solution :-)